# How much do we know about the geography of the Divide books?

Tags: geography, the-divide, elizabeth-kay

Elizabeth Kay's *Divide* books feature a variety of different places: in the first book, Geddon, Tromm Fell, Tiratattle, and Andria; in the second book, Kaflabad and the secret city whose name I forget; in the third book, Yergud and Vattan.

**How much do we know canonically about the relative geography of these places?**

For example, we know that Tromm Fell lies on a continental divide and Geddon is close by, and that Andria is further east and on the coast. Tiratattle is somewhere between the two (perhaps further north or south?), and presumably the desert lands around Kaflabad are further south while the snowy Yergud and Vattan are further north. How much detail can be gone into here? Does there exist a canonical map of the world, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does there exist a canonical map of the world, perhaps?

**Yes.** I just found this map, presumably designed by the author herself, available [on her website](http://www.elizabethkay.co.uk/kaflabad.html):

[image: map]

It shows Geddon, Tiratattle, Andria, Kaflabad, and some other settlements which (as far as I remember) aren't even mentioned in the books. This seems likely to be the best information available on the geography of the world of the *Divide* books.